# Does anyone know how to output strings in a given format from a text?

Tags: python

I just began to learn Python and I'm quite confused about how to find all string elements in a given format from a text. For example:

```
#  USE OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE. 
#
#
alert tcp $HOME_NET any -> 50.116.1.225 22 (msg:"ET CNC Shadowserver Reported CnC Server Port 22 Group 1"; flow:to_server; flags:S; reference:url,doc.emergingthreats.net/bin/view/Main/BotCC; reference:url,www.shadowserver.org; threshold: type limit, track by_src, seconds 360, count 1; classtype:trojan-activity; flowbits:set,ET.Evil; flowbits:set,ET.BotccIP; sid:2405000; rev:4483;)
```

This is one very small part of the whole text, what I'm trying to do is to get all IP addresses like 50.116.1.225 22 from the text. I've tried for quite a while and I'd be more than grateful if someone could answer my question.

Comment: Are all of the lines of text in that format, with `{text} -> IP {bracketed stuff}` (where `{text}` and `{bracketed stuff}` is basically the same as the example line above?

Comment: Use a [regex](https://www.regex101.com/r/ffpBvL/1)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Don't tell us that you have tried. Show us exactly what you have tried and we can give pointers how to proceed from there.

Comment: How to use `regex` to match an IP address: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20060522-08/?p=31113

Comment: Yes,all of the lines from the text are in this format, but some lines have lists after '->', which contain many IP addresses. So I intended to split this text by ' ' after then, I can detect which element in this split list is in this format or is a list. If it's in this format, append it to a new list, elif it's a list, append every element(which is also IPs\) of this list to that new list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you'll want to use regular expressions. If I understand the questions correctly, the following is simple but not perfect, if your text is already a string (it's not specified what your text is) named `alerts`:

```
import re

results = re.findall("\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}", alerts)

for item in results:
    print(item)
```

output:

```
50.116.1.225
```

Comment: Yes! that's what I'm trying to achieve. Thank you dude

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use regular expressions.  This lets you pluck out specific patterns of characters from a string.

```
import re

pat = re.compile(r'\b(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}
                  (?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\b')

for ip in re.findall(pat, text):
     print(ip)
```